# GWT Editor Framework with simple sub-Editor and null fields

Tags: gwt, editor

### UPDATE2: Updated example to demonstrate original problem.  If Person.address is originally null, binding fails.

I'm trying to get a very simple GWT editor framework example working with sub-Editors. I followed the pseudo-example here http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html

When I call driver.flush(), the value for Person.address is always null if the original Person.address is null - regardless of whether I typed in a value in the address's city field.

Here's my very simple POJO classes.

```
public class Person {

    private Address address;
    private String name;
    ... getters and setters
}

public class Address {

    private String city;
    ... getters and setters
}
```

Now the editors.

```
public class PersonEditor extends DialogBox implements Editor<Person> {

    TextBox nameEditor = new TextBox();

    AddressEditor addressEditor = new AddressEditor();

    Button saveButton = new Button("Save");

    public PersonEditor() {
        VerticalPanel vp = new VerticalPanel();
        vp.add(nameEditor);
        vp.add(addressEditor);
        vp.add(saveButton);
        add(vp);
    }

    public HandlerRegistration addSaveClickHandler(ClickHandler handler) {
        return saveButton.addClickHandler(handler);
    }
}
```

The address editor couldn't be simpler.  It's just a TextBox

```
public class AddressEditor extends Composite implements Editor<Address> {

    TextBox cityEditor = new TextBox();

    public AddressEditor() {
        initWidget(cityEditor);
    }
}
```

And the test program.  If you uncomment p.setAddress it will work fine.

```
// Empty interface declaration, similar to UiBinder
interface Driver extends SimpleBeanEditorDriver<Person, PersonEditor> {
}

// Create the Driver
Driver driver = GWT.create(Driver.class);

@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
    Person p = new Person();
    p.setName("Bob");

    Address a = new Address();
    a.setCity("Los Angeles");
    //p.setAddress(a);

    PersonEditor editor = new PersonEditor();
    editor.addSaveClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Person edited = driver.flush();

            if (driver.hasErrors()) {
                GWT.log("Has errors");
                return;
            }
            GWT.log("Edited Name: " + edited.getName());
            GWT.log("Edited City: " + edited.getAddress().getCity());
        }
    });
    driver.initialize(editor);
    driver.edit(p);
    editor.center(); // show the dialog
}
```

When I click Save, a NPE will be thrown regardless if I type in a city or not.  If the original person object has some non-null address, the binding will work fine "both" ways.

Comment: After thinking about it for a little while I suppose this behavior makes sense.  GWT lacks reflection so perhaps it cannot generate a new "Address".  I would have imagined the generated class magic would take care of this.  The problem is for every object using editor framework, all nested properties (and their children...) have to be traversed to ensure there's no null objects in the entire object graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, it won't automatically create missing instances. This could be a feature in some cases, especially when using `OptionalFieldEditor`.

One thought is to make your model's constructor automatically create those fields, or when you create them new on the client go ahead and descend, creating new instances as you go.

If this is going to be a general need and you feel like getting your hands a bit dirty, some ideas for you to work from - the editor driver will generate a hierarchy of delegates, which can be visited using `EditorDriver.accept(EditorVisitor)`. This will allow you to see what the current model is, and if it is something that should be initialized before proceeding. `EditorContext` provides a few helpful methods here, such as `setInModel` and `getEditedType`, the question will be how to construct these items as you find them missing, and when to leave them blank (Date, String, and boxed primitives, for examples, but you have have other use cases where you want them blank). I would make a `Generator` for this that functions somewhat like the RPC deserializer, keeping track of possibly needed constructors, and mapping them to `Class` instances.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate this is a slightly old one, but I too faced this issue, having recently started playing with the editor framework.

I found the simplest way to implement the functionality required is to have your address "editor" implement LeafValueEditor. This requires you to provide implementations for getValue() and setValue(), which will be called by the driver when flush() and edit() are called respectively. This will happen irrespective of whether the backing object is null or not.

I have provided an example below. I tested this and it works perfectly. Hope it does for you too!

```
public class AddressField extends Composite implements LeafValueEditor<AddressDTO> {

    interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, AddressField> {}
    private static Binder uiBinder = GWT.create(Binder.class);

    @UiConstructor
    public AddressField() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    @UiField TextBox line1;
    @UiField TextBox line2;
    @UiField TextBox town;
    @UiField TextBox postcode;
    @UiField TextBox county;
    @UiField TextBox country;

    @Override
    public void setValue(AddressDTO value) {
        line1.setValue(value == null ? null : value.getLine1());
        line2.setValue(value == null ? null : value.getLine2());
        town.setValue(value == null ? null : value.getTown());
        postcode.setValue(value == null ? null : value.getPostcode());
        county.setValue(value == null ? null : value.getCounty());
        country.setValue(value == null ? null : value.getCountry());
    }

    @Override
    public AddressDTO getValue() {
        return new AddressDTO(line1.getValue(), line2.getValue(), postcode.getValue(), town.getValue(), county.getValue(), country.getValue());
    }
}
```